# How to know the url served by my SVN server?

Tags: svn, networking

I just install and run `svnserve` on my Unix machine with following command:

```
/usr/bin/svnserve --daemon --pid-file=/var/run/svnserve.pid --listen-port=3690
```

The service is running.

My IP server is 10.33.37.2 and my port is opened:

```
nmap -sS 10.33.37.2
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
3690/tcp  open  svn
```

Then I create a repository:

```
svnadmin create /srv/svn/myRepoName
```

Now I want to work on this new repo, I test a checkout with the following URL:

```
svn://10.33.37.2:3690/svn/myRepoName
```

But I get the error:

```
No repository found in 'svn://10.33.37.2:3690/svn/myRepoName'
```

How can I find my repo URL? I looked into *[SVNADMIN](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.html)*'s documentation but I don't found any command to get it.

Is there a SVN configuration to perform?

Comment: You got it, I thought it was a `svnadmin` option, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the root folder of the repositories to `svnserve`:

```
svnserve ... -r /srv
```

That will let you move downward from that folder (e.g. in /svn).